# PL/SQL procedure exception compile error

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I want write procedure which create in temporary table in temp_line and LOOP in temp_line to check and get exception.

```
create or replace package body cux_bpm_hr_030_040_2 is 
FUNCTION save_hr_030_040(p_event_record_id       number,
                       p_share_log_id          number,
                       p_oa_flow_doc_header_id number,
                       p_created_by            number) return number is
v_data_line_id        number;
v_total_amount        number;
v_annual_vct_hour     number;
v_ot_vct_hour         number;
v_annual_vct_req_hour number;
v_ot_vct_req_hour     number;
v_string_date         varchar(100);
e_req_hour_error exception;
e_req_hour_error1 exception;
v_num                 number;

begin
select count(*) 
into v_num 
from user_tables 
where table_name = 'temp_line';
```

`if v_num < 1 then 
　　execute immediate ('CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE temp_line ( 
　　holiday_id VARCHAR2(6),
    holiday_begin_date DATE,
    holiday_begin_hour (6),
    holiday_begin_min (6),
    holiday_end_date DATE,
    holiday_end_hour (6),
    holiday_end_min (6)
　　) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS'); 
　　end if;`

```
execute immediate ('FOR recitem IN(select * from oa_tplt019_line_01_v l where l.oa_flow_doc_header_id = p_oa_flow_doc_header_id)


LOOP 
insert into temp_line(holiday_id,holiday_begin_date,holiday_begin_hour,holiday_begin_min,holiday_end_date, holiday_end_hour,holiday_end_min)
values
(recitem.C_025,recitem.C_027,recitem.C_028,recitem.C_029,recitem.C_030,recitem.D_001,reitem.D_002)  ENDLOOP;');`

LOOP
Declare
        begin_diff varchar2(8);
        diff       varchar2(8);
        holiday_begin_date   number;
        holiday_end_date     number;
select nvl(l.holiday_begin_date, 0),nvl(l.holiday_end_date, 0)
into holiday_begin_date,holiday_end_date
from temp_line l

begin_diff = holiday_begin_date - sys_date
diff =  holiday_end_date - holiday_begin_date
IF begin_diff > 3 then
  raise e_req_hour_error;
  ENDIF;
IF diff < 0 then
  raise e_req_hour_error1;
  ENDIF; ENDLOOP;
```

I'm getting compile error:

```
Compilation errors for PACKAGE BODY KL_BPMDEV.CUX_BPM_HR_030_040_2

Error: PLS-00103:  Encountered the symbol ""when expecting one of the following:
        ( begin case declare end
          exception exit for goto if loop mod null pragma raise return
          select update while with <an identifier>
          <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
          continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
          savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
Line: 25
Text: ﹛ --create temporary table
```

Comment: Can you try reproducing your error using some dummy code?  That way you can slowly remove code until you narrow down the cause.  Once you have a *minimal* procedure that reproduces your error, and if you still need help, then you can post that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply！
I try to compiler and get error message when I try to create temp_line this table

Comment: Your code contains multiple syntax errors - `ENDIF` instead of `END IF`, `ENDLOOP` not `END LOOP`, not brackets for `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` - which you could fix yourself by [reading the PL/SQL documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#CIHEAFBJ).

Comment: However, the main problem is that you have misunderstood GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE constructs.  In Oracle these are *permanent* structures: it's just the data which is temporary (it doesn't persist beyond the session).  That should make your program simpler.

Comment: Thanks for all of your reply！
I wrote ABAP at begin, and has begun to write ORACLE PL/SQL in recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major error in your code is you are declaring some other variables inside BEGIN ... END. You can only declare before your function BEGIN. You need to learn the basics of writing functions/procedures. See [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions.php)

Apart from that, you have several debugging errors you need to fix. The following function has been compiled successfully. Please look at the comments where I made corrections

```
create or replace FUNCTION save_hr_030_040(p_event_record_id       number,
                       p_share_log_id          number,
                       p_oa_flow_doc_header_id number,
                       p_created_by            number) return number is
v_data_line_id        number;
v_total_amount        number;
v_annual_vct_hour     number;
v_ot_vct_hour         number;
v_annual_vct_req_hour number;
v_ot_vct_req_hour     number;
v_string_date         varchar(100);
e_req_hour_error exception;
e_req_hour_error1 exception;
v_num                 number;
    begin_diff varchar2(8);     --You cannot declare inside BEGIN/END, you can only declare in the declaration section
    diff       varchar2(8);
    holiday_begin_date   number;
    holiday_end_date     number;

begin
select count(*) 
into v_num 
from user_tables 
where table_name = 'temp_line';
if v_num < 1 then 
if v_num < 1 then 
  execute immediate 'CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE temp_line ( 
   holiday_id VARCHAR2(6),
   holiday_begin_date DATE,
   holiday_begin_hour VARCHAR2(6),
   holiday_begin_min VARCHAR2(6),
   holiday_end_date DATE,
   holiday_end_hour VARCHAR2(6),
   holiday_end_min VARCHAR2(6)
  ) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS'; 
  end if;
execute immediate ('FOR recitem IN(select * from oa_tplt019_line_01_v l where l.oa_flow_doc_header_id = p_oa_flow_doc_header_id); 


LOOP 
insert into temp_line(holiday_id,holiday_begin_date,holiday_begin_hour,holiday_begin_min,holiday_end_date, holiday_end_hour,holiday_end_min)
values
(recitem.C_025,recitem.C_027,recitem.C_028,recitem.C_029,recitem.C_030,recitem.D_001,reitem.D_002)  ENDLOOP;');   --remove extra '`' 

LOOP
select nvl(l.holiday_begin_date, 0),nvl(l.holiday_end_date, 0)
into holiday_begin_date,holiday_end_date
from temp_line l;

begin_diff := holiday_begin_date - sys_date;   --missing semi colon
diff :=  holiday_end_date - holiday_begin_date; --missing semi colon
IF begin_diff > 3 then
  raise e_req_hour_error;
  END IF;
IF diff < 0 then
  raise e_req_hour_error1;
  END IF; END LOOP;   --These are not ENDIF and ENDLOOP, you need to add space betwween them

      end if;
      end;
```

Whether you copied parts of this code, or you wrote it entirely yourself, you need to use your editor to fix these kinds of errors. I see you tagged plsqldeveloper. The tool tells you exactly what errors you have, and you can start fixing them one by one until you get it compiled.

Comment: Sorry！Thanks for your rely！
I follow your step.
But its seems the temporary table is't exist.
Table：temp_line

Comment: @RoyWu According to your code, creating temporary table will only run `if v_num < 1 then`. But what the value of `v_num`. I do not see it assigned anywhere in your function

Comment: The step just what I want to check  temporary table is exist or not at begin
so I count the temporary it will be 0 at first.
By the way I have been delete if v_num < 1 then .

Comment: @RoyWu your datatype for the temporary table were either missing or wrong. I changed them to `VARCHAR2`. I could create temp table now.